# JavaScript : How do i push new column/row to the JavaScript Array during for..loop iteration?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

i have my service response as below and i want to push a new row/column when i am iterating the array using for.. loop?

**Service Response**

```
"message":
{
   "student" [

     {
       "name" : "student1", 
       "oDate" : "03/03/2016",
       "oTime" :  "5:00 PM"
     },
     {
       "name" : "student2", 
       "oDate" : "03/03/2016",
       "oTime" :  "6:00 PM"
},{
       "name" : "student3", 
       "oDate" : "03/03/2016",
       "oTime" :  "7:00 PM"
} ]        
     }

}     

var myArray =[];

for(var i=0; i<data.message.student.length; i++)
{
var sessionDate = a.oDate + a.oTime;
myArray.push(data.message.student[i]);
}
```

How do i push my **sessionDate** to the data.message.student[i] object and it got pushed further into myArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this help

```
var myArray = [];

for(var i=0; i < data.message.student.length; i++) {
    data.message.student[i].sessionDate = a.oDate + a.oTime;
    myArray.push(data.message.student[i]);
}
```

Regards.-

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for generating an array.

```js
var data = { message: { "student": [{ "name": "student1", "oDate": "03/03/2016", "oTime": "5:00 PM" }, { "name": "student2", "oDate": "03/03/2016", "oTime": "6:00 PM" }, { "name": "student3", "oDate": "03/03/2016", "oTime": "7:00 PM" }] } },
    myArray = data.message.student.map(function (a) {
        a.sessionDate = a.oDate + ' ' + a.oTime;
        return a;
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(myArray, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thank you @Nina Scholz for your answer.